# VB.NET Combobox and picture box

Tags: vb.net, combobox, picturebox

If someone can help me I will appreciate it. Thanks in advance,
I have a combobox with the values databinding inside a database, I want when I move the records next/previous base on what combobox value is a picturebox display a picture I have stored in my resources.

When I change with mouse combobox value the picture change but when I move between records not. What am I missing there?

```
  Private Sub TypeComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TypeComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged

     If TypeComboBox.SelectedItem().ToString() = "1" Then
           PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.image1
     End if
     If TypeComboBox.SelectedItem().ToString() = "2" Then
             PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.image2
     End if

      End Sub

Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, ByVal keyData As Keys) As Boolean

    'detect left arrow key
    If keyData = Keys.Left Then
        If Me.ToolsBindingSource.Position = 0 Then
            Me.ToolsBindingSource.MoveLast()
            Return True
        Else
            Me.ToolsBindingSource.MovePrevious()
            Return True
        End If
    End If
    'detect right arrow key
    If keyData = Keys.Right Then
        If Me.ToolsBindingSource.Position = Me.ToolsBindingSource.Count - 1 Then
            Me.ToolsBindingSource.MoveFirst()
            Return True
        Else
            Me.ToolsBindingSource.MoveNext()
            Return True
        End If
    End If
    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
```

Comment: Perhaps you should explain EXACTLY what data is contained in your `ComboBox` and EXACTLY how that relates to your images.  You ALWAYS need to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.

Comment: @jmcilhinney sorry i thought that was clear from code, in combobox i have add from vs2017 edit items not by code. I have 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 e.t.c. it suppose that is simple text (string) or i am wrong? Relates to my images not very clear to me, i have in my resources some PNG files with 1,2,3,4,5 and i want when combobox have the string 1 show the PNG file with 1 e.t.c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you create an array containing the `Images` at the start.  You should not repeatedly access the same property of `My.Resources` because it will create a new object each time.  E.g.

```
Private images As Image() = {My.Resources.image1, My.Resources.image2}
```

You can then simply use the `SelectedIndex` of the `ComboBox` as an index into that array.  As long as the two lists are in the same order, the actual values in the `ComboBox` are irrelevant.  E.g.

```
PictureBox1.Image = images(TypeComboBox.SelectedIndex)
```

EDIT: Another option would be to create a list that relates the `Images` and the text, bind that to the `ComboBox` and then use the `SelectedValue`, e.g.

```
Dim imagesAndText = {Tuple.Create("1", My.Resources.image1),
                     Tuple.Create("2", My.Resources.image2)}

With TypeComboBox
    .DisplayMember = "Item1"
    .ValueMember = "Item2"
    .DataSource = imagesAndText
End With
```

By passing a `String` and an `Image` to `Tuple.Create`, you get a `Tuple(Of String, Image)`.  Tuples have properties of the types specified and named `Item1`, `Item2`, etc.  In this case, `Item1` would return the `String` value and `Item2` the `Image`.  After binding, you can access the selected `Image` via the `SelectedValue` property, e.g.

```
PictureBox1.Image = DirectCast(TypeComboBox.SelectedValue, Image)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your help make me understood more about coding. It works ok but after so much changes to make it work, i use other approach and at the end i find why didn't work from the start. It was from database i had it at nchar(10), when i change it to nvchar work like a charm. Thanks again

Comment: I have made an edit that it would be worth your while taking a look at.

Comment: @jimcihinney Thanks a lot, i will keep in mind. I didn't manage to work with all my images and i will keep the 1st option look more tidy.